# EF Core - Select Parent Value If Null

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to cut down on the size of my Json response / DB query so I am selecting only the required columns in my code.

I have the following tables (lots more columns in all tables but simplified for my post):

**Product**
ProductId (PK)
Name
Manufacturer
InternalSku
ExternalSku
Ean

**ProductVariation**
ProductVariationId (PK)
InternalSku
ExternalSku
Ean
ProductId (FK)

**ProductImage**
ProductImageId (PK)
IsDefault (Bit)
ImageUrl
ProductId (FK)
ProductVariationId (FK / Null)

I have created simple models for both Product and ProductVariation (**ProductSimple**, **ProductVariationSimple**).

My code will only select the first image for each. With my current code, I am able to achieve nearly what I want but I have a problem with the Product Images.

**Product** can have images and also **ProductVariation** can have images.  However, if **ProductVariation** does not have any images, I want to select the image of the parent product (if available).  Is this possible?

This is my current code:

````
var products = await _context.Product
            .Include(e => e.ProductImages.Where(p => p.IsDefault == true && p.ProductVariationId == null))
            .Include(m => m.Manufacturer)
            .Include(v => v.ProductVariations).ThenInclude(x => x.ProductImages.Where(p => p.IsDefault == true && p.ProductVariationId == x.ProductVariationId))

            .Select(p => new Product()
            {
                ProductId = p.ProductId,
                Name = p.Name,
                Manufacturer = p.Manufacturer,
                ManufacturerSku = p.ManufacturerSku,
                InternalSku = p.InternalSku,
                Ean = p.Ean,
                ProductImages = p.ProductImages,
                ProductVariations = p.ProductVariations.Select(x => new ProductVariation { 
                    ProductVariationId = x.ProductVariationId,
                    Name = x.Name,
                    InternalSku = x.InternalSku,
                    ManufacturerSku = x.ManufacturerSku,
                    Ean = x.Ean,
                    ProductImages = x.ProductImages,
                    ProductId = x.ProductId
                }).ToList()
            }
            )
            .ToListAsync();
            
            var productSimple = products.Select(
                e => new ProductSimple
                {
                    ProductId = e.ProductId,
                    Name = e.Name,
                    ManufacturerName = e.Manufacturer?.Name,
                    ManufacturerSku = e.ManufacturerSku,
                    InternalSku = e.InternalSku,
                    Ean = e.Ean,
                    ImageUrl = e.ProductImages.FirstOrDefault()?.ImageUrl,
                    ProductVariationSimples = e.ProductVariations.Select(
                        v => new ProductVariationSimple
                        {
                            ProductVariationId = v.ProductVariationId,
                            Name = v.Name,
                            InternalSku = v.InternalSku,
                            ManufacturerSku = v.ManufacturerSku,
                            Ean = v.Ean,
                            ProductId = v.ProductId,
                            ImageUrl = v.ProductImages.FirstOrDefault()?.ImageUrl  //This is where my problem is. I want to select first image of the variation or first image of parent if not available
                        })
                }
                ).AsQueryable();

            return productSimple;```

Many thanks in advance.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like below.

```
ImageUrl = v.ProductImages.Any() ? v.ProductImages.First().ImageUrl : e.ProductImages.FirstOrDefault()?.ImageUrl
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
                    v => new ProductVariationSimple
                    {
                        ProductVariationId = v.ProductVariationId,
                        Name = v.Name,
                        InternalSku = v.InternalSku,
                        ManufacturerSku = v.ManufacturerSku,
                        Ean = v.Ean,
                        ProductId = v.ProductId,
                        ImageUrl = v.ProductImages.FirstOrDefault()?.ImageUrl?? e.ProductImages.FirstOrDefault()
                    })
```

Let me know if it works.